# Why are my hover styles not being applied?

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm creating a button with hover and reveal animation text using opacity but it's not working:

```css
.text-hello{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .3s ease;
    position: absolute;
}

.icon-hello:hover .text-hello{
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="test" style="background-color: #eaeaea; position: absolute; bottom: 9%; right: 10%;">
    <img src="{{ url('images/res1.svg')}}" style="width: 35px; height:35px;" class="icon-hello">
    <span class="text-hello">Hello World</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the adjacent sibling selector (`+`):

```
.icon-hello:hover + .text-hello {
    // styles
}
```

It will grab the element immediately following the first one.

Comment: ohh, i see ! but i wanna when i hover image and reveal text beside that :(. have u an idea for me?

Comment: I modified the codepen so that the text would go to the right side, you can fork it to play around with where you want the text positioned. I had to add a "wrapper div" around the image and the text, so that the text would stay positioned around the image. Also, I moved all your inline styles into classes because it was easier for me to manipulate it that way. So take a look at the link again and let me know if that helps get you in the right direction :)